# R string list breaking the console even though length <500

Tags: r, list

I am making a word cloud that takes a number of URLs and makes the word cloud. it is working great so far as long as I keep the list of URLs less than ~50. and it is not because of the cloud generator but because of the c {base} function not willing to take my urls in.

```
DaLinks <- c("http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/producttesting","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/medical","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/hilton-iso-9001-and-iso-14001-worldwide","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/training","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/process-safety","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/dekra-annual-financial-press-conference","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/telecommunications-tl-9000","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/ferrari-458-italia-wins-dekra-green-challenge","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/executive-overview","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/dr.-cem-o.-onus-promoted-to-managing-director-of-systems","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/certification-marks","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/national-biosolids","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/iso-14001-environmental-management","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/medical-services","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/epeat-events","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/switchgear","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/iso-50001-overview","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/educational-testing-service-certified-to-iso-9001","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/refrigerator-testing","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/iecex","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/power-tools","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/fm-inspections","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/health-care","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/contact","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/automotive","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/medical-product","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/rohs-testing1","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/careers","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/hilton-worldwide-certified-to-iso-50001","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/export-support","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/dekra-continues-to-grow","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/medical-medical","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/manufacturing","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/medical-system","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/cmdcas-program","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/aimdd","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/government","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/aerospace-and-aviation","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/managementsystem","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/new-iso-50001-certification-service","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/household-appliances","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/atex-153","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/fabric-development-as9100-rev.-c","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/advanced-surveillance-and-reassessment-procedures-asrp","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/emc","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/service-providers","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/professional-electronics","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/export-support-services","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/industry","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/proposal-request-forms","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/emc-testing","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/inspection-services","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/dekra-certified-as-as9101e","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/138","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/volvo-na-iso-50001-and-sep-certified","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/food-feed","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/sustainability","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/tissues-of-animal-origin","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/fda-qsit-inspections","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/emc-e4","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/installation-components","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/home","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/explosion-safety","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/fm-for-hazardous-locations","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/superior-energy-performance-sep","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/ohsas-18001-occupational-health","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/in-company-training","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/dekra-manual-notice","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/transportation-iatf-16949","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/contact?p_p_id=1_WAR_webformportlet_INSTANCE_VY4s&p_p_lifecycle=2&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_cacheability=cacheLevelPage&p_p_col_id=column-2&p_p_col_pos=2&p_p_col_count=4&_1_WAR_webformportlet_INSTANCE_VY4s_cmd=captcha","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/appliance-components","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/iso-20000-it-management","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/transportation-ts-16949","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/atex-114","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/system-certification-services","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/emc-fcc","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/dekra-certification-to-present-webinar-on-sustainability-management-systems","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/keihin-iso-50001-certification","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/news","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/dekra","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/atex-114-management-system","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/medical-testing","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/process-industries","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/cables-and-wiring","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/accreditations-usa","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/iso-9001-quality-management","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/retail","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/cca","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/dekra-expands-range-of-training-courses-in-north-america","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/enec","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/iso-13485-medical-device-certification","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/iso-50001-training","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/r-label","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/e-newsletter-of-iaqg-aerospace-accreditation-body","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/it","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/led-performance-mark","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/supply-chain-services","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/ivdd","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/iso-50001-internal-auditing","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/445","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/lighting","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/441","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/mdd","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/ivdd","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/iso-27001-information-security","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/water-management-iso-14046","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/transfer-of-certification","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/environment","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/ce","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/rtte","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/417","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/cb","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/iso-50001-energy-management","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/415","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/420","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/electrical","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/construction","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/consumer-electronics","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/photometric","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/as9100-aerospace","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/green-electronics-epeat","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/attestation-of-conformity","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/dekra-ranked-among-top-50-german-brands-for-2015","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/impartiality","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/form_download_whitepaper","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/behavioral-science-technology","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/request-form_12","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/medical-personnel","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/electrostatic-discharge-esd","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/plant-safety","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/supplier-audits","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/kema-keur","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/ip-nema","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/anab-iso-50001-energy-management","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/nissan-sep-and-iso-50001-certification","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/kema-quality-now-called-dekra","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/thomas-and-betts","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/transport","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/tiis-approval","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/iso-50001-implementation-and-operations","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/fda-510-k-reviews","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/chemical-testing","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/productcertification","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/services","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/number-of-employees-2013","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/automotive-lighting-testing","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/keysight-technologies-certified-to-iso-9001-2015","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/406","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/iec-60601","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/subaru-of-indiana","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/time-to-market","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/why-dekra","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/access-to-the-us","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/405")
```

it's a long list, but it has only ~160 strings. lists in R 32 can take up to 2^31-1 elements.
when I try to run that one line. I get

```
> DaLinks <- c("http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/producttesting","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/medical","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/hilton-iso-9001-and-iso-14001-worldwide","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/training","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/process-safety","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/dekra-annual-financial-press-conference","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/telecommunications-tl-9000","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/ferrari-458-italia-wins-dekra-green-challenge","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/executive-overview","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/dr.-cem-o.-onus-promoted-to-managing-director-of-systems","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/certification-marks","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/national-biosolids","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/iso-14001-environmental-management","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/medical-services","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/epeat-events","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/switchgear","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/iso-50001-overview","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/educational-testing-service-certified-to-iso-9001","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/refrigerator-testing","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/iecex","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/power-tools","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/fm-inspections","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/health-care","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/contact","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/automotive","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/medical-product","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/rohs-testing1","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/careers","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/hilton-worldwide-certified-to-iso-50001","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/export-support","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/dekra-continues-to-grow","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/medical-medical","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/manufacturing","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/medical-system","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/cmdcas-program","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/aimdd","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/government","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/aerospace-and-aviation","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/managementsystem","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/new-iso-50001-certification-service","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/household-appliances","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/atex-153","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/fabric-development-as9100-rev.-c","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/advanced-surveillance-and-reassessment-procedures-asrp","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/emc","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/service-providers","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/professional-electronics","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/export-support-services","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/industry","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/proposal-request-forms","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/emc-testing","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/inspection-services","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/dekra-certified-as-as9101e","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/138","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/volvo-na-iso-50001-and-sep-certified","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/food-feed","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/sustainability","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/tissues-of-animal-origin","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/fda-qsit-inspections","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/emc-e4","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/installation-components","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/home","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/explosion-safety","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/fm-for-hazardous-locations","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/superior-energy-performance-sep","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/ohsas-18001-occupational-health","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/in-company-training","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/dekra-manual-notice","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/transportation-iatf-16949","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/contact?p_p_id=1_WAR_webformportlet_INSTANCE_VY4s&p_p_lifecycle=2&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_cacheability=cacheLevelPage&p_p_col_id=column-2&p_p_col_pos=2&p_p_col_count=4&_1_WAR_webformportlet_INSTANCE_VY4s_cmd=captcha","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/appliance-components","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/iso-20000-it-management","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/transportation-ts-16949","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/atex-114","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/system-certification-services","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/emc-fcc","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/dekra-certification-to-present-webinar-on-sustainability-management-systems","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/keihin-iso-50001-certification","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/news","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/dekra","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/atex-114-management-system","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/medical-testing","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/process-industries","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/cables-and-wiring","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/accreditations-usa","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/iso-9001-quality-management","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/retail","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/cca","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/dekra-expands-range-of-training-courses-in-north-america","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/enec","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/iso-13485-medical-device-certification","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/iso-50001-training","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/r-label","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/e-newsletter-of-iaqg-aerospace-accreditation-body","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/it","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/led-performance-mark","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/supply-chain-services","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/ivdd","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/iso-50001-internal-auditing","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/445","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/lighting","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/441","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/mdd","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/ivdd","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/iso-27001-information-security","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/water-management-iso-14046","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/transfer-of-certification","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/environment","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/ce","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/rtte","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/417","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/cb","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/iso-50001-energy-management","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/415","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/420","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/electrical","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/construction","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/consumer-electronics","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/photometric","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/as9100-aerospace","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/green-electronics-epeat","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/attestation-of-conformity","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/dekra-ranked-among-top-50-german-brands-for-2015","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/impartiality","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/form_download_whitepaper","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/behavioral-science-technology","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/request-form_12","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/medical-personnel","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/electrostatic-discharge-esd","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/plant-safety","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/supplier-audits","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/kema-keur","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/ip-nema","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/anab-iso-50001-energy-management","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/nissan-sep-and-iso-50001-certification","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/kema-quality-now-called-dekra","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/thomas-and-betts","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/transport","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/tiis-approval","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/iso-50001-implementation-and-operations","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/fda-510-k-reviews","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/chemical-testing","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/productcertification","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/services","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/number-of-employees-2013","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/automotive-lighting-testing","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/keysight-technologies-certified-to-iso-9001-2015","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/406","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/iec-60601","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/subaru-of-indiana","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/time-to-market","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/why-dekra","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/access-to-the-us","http://www.dekra-certification.us/en/405")
+ 
+ 
+ 
+ 
+ 
+
```

and the plus signs continues until I escape the console. this is frustrating me severely.
everything run on low number of strings. so this is clearly a c{base} issue. any input or help around it?
PS: the contents are used later for a for x in list loop

Comment: You probably have an unmatched quotation mark somewhere.

Comment: Also, if you have a huge list of strings, put it in a text file and use readLines() function.

Comment: works for me in RStudio console